# Is my account constantly violated?

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

It's the second time I change my gmail password and I keep receiving this warning ( see image). What can I do ?

[image]

Comment: You might want to enable the [two factor authentication](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/09/more-secure-cloud-for-millions-of.html) as well.

Comment: See [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18047/gmail-account-hacked/) as well.

Comment: Are the dates listed from before or after you changed your password?

Answer (score 1):

Running antivirus to remove known keyloggers is the first step.
You can read more about them here: http://www.securelist.com/en/analysis/204791931/Keyloggers_How_they_work_and_how_to_detect_them_Part_1

If you do not have an antivirus software, try Avast: http://www.avast.com/en-us/index

Beyond that, since you have been compromised, you will want to ensure that you do not use the same password for all your online accounts.

If you're worried about you password being guessed, try to make it a longer password (password crackers run faster against short passwords), and don't use things that are available to people online: your birthday, pet's name, children's name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep getting hacked even after changing your password, then you might want to run an antivirus scan on your computer. Alternately, make sure you also change the password on any recovery e-mail address too.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a keylogger on your computer.  Run some anti-virus or malware removal programs.